# no data is transmitted from the popup menu

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an `item` card to which data is transferred from the database, then when I click on the `order` button on the card, I have a popup menu and the data in the pop-up menu is also taken from the database, when I click on the `order` button in the popup menu, they should be transferred using ajax to another file, but when I check if there is something in the `orderData` variable, it turns out that there is not. I can't understand why they are not transferred there.

I understand that when a popup menu opens, it somehow blocks access to data and therefore the `orderData` variable is empty. Can you help me fix it somehow

```html
  <div class="main_123">
    <?php foreach($info as $data): ?>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $data['image'];?>"></div>
        <div class="whiteList">
          <div class="brand">
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data["brand"]); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="carName">
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data["name"]); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="number">Номер:
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['number']); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="fuel">fuel:
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data['fuel']); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="p-m">Price:
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data["PriceMin"]); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="itm-order" id="itm-order"><button class="popup-button" onclick="showPopup(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data)); ?>)">Order</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="popup" class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="closePopup()">&times;</span>
    <div class="popup-image"><img id="popup-image" src="" alt="Car Image"></div>
    <h2 id="popup-brand"></h2>
    <p id="popup-name"></p>
    <p id="popup-number"></p>
    <p id="popup-fuel"></p>
    <p id="popup-price"></p>
    <div class="popup-order"><button type="button" data-userid="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">Order</button></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".popup-order").click(function() {
    var item = $(this).closest(".item");
    var userId = $(this).data("userid"); // Получаем user_id из data-атрибута кнопки "Заказать"
    var image = item.find(".image img").attr("src");
    var brand = item.find(".brand").text();
    var carName = item.find(".carName").text();
    var number = item.find(".number").text().split(":")[1];
    var fuel = item.find(".fuel").text();

    var orderData = {
      userId: userId,
      image: image,
      brand: brand,
      carName: carName,
      number: number,
      fuel: fuel
    };

    // Отправляем данные на сервер
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "add_to_cart.php",
      data: orderData,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(brand);
        alert("Товар добавлен в корзину!");
        closePopup();
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // Обработка ошибок
        console.log("Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса на сервер.");
      }
    });
  });
});

function showPopup(data) {
  var dataImage = document.getElementById("popup-image");
  var dataBrand = document.getElementById("popup-brand");
  var dataName = document.getElementById("popup-name");
  var dataNumber = document.getElementById("popup-number");
  var dataFuel = document.getElementById("popup-fuel");
  var dataPrice = document.getElementById("popup-price");

  dataImage.src = data.image;
  dataBrand.innerHTML = data.brand;
  dataName.innerHTML = data.name;
  dataNumber.innerHTML = "Номер: " + data.number;
  dataFuel.innerHTML = "Бензин: " + data.fuel;
  dataPrice.innerHTML = "Цена: " + data.PriceMin + " руб.";

  popup.style.display = "flex";
}

function closePopup() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  popup.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Is your HTML snippet above contained in a `form` element? If so, clicking the `button` element will be submitting the form and bypassing your AJAX.

Comment: Do you specifically mean that the `$(".popup-order").click(function() {` handler isn't doing what you expect?  When you use the browser's script debugger to place a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  At a glance for example, what does this find?: `var item = $(this).closest(".item");`  The structure containing `.popup-order` is entirely separate from the structure containing `.item`, isn't it?  Are you trying to get data from the element which invoked the popup, or from the popup itself?

Comment: I would add the click handler to the button and not the div `popup-order`. I don't think that is your problem but it certainly is an odd choice.

Comment: @David starting from the first line in the function `$(".popup-order").click(function() {` it cannot take data from `item` (that is, I want to take data from the element that calls popup menu)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, it's not in `form` because I need to send data without refreshing the page